# CSR Documentation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jslink, client-side-rendering

I am looking for CSR Documentation.  If I Google something from the Server-Side API, I get the documentation right away.

> For example, Googling `SPWeb`, the first result is the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.
>   However, when I try the same thing with `CSR functions`, I get examples but no documentation.

A couple of things that I hope documentation will clear up: In the following code I have 2 issues:

1. `SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides()` expects an object.  Where can I find a complete list of the keys and what I can expect them to do?
2. Where did `RenderItemTemplate` come from?  After sifting through a number of examples, I just happened to come across `RenderItemTemplate`.   It isn't associated with an object, so there could be a whole bunch of helpful global functions that I know nothing about.

   ```
   function () {

     var itemCtx = {};
     itemCtx.Templates = {};

       itemCtx.Templates.Header = HeaderOverrideFunc;
       itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
       itemCtx.Templates.Footer = FooterOverrideFunc;

     SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

   })();


   function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {
     if (ctx.ListTitle != "My List") {
        return RenderItemTemplate(ctx);
     }
     return "<li style='background-color: #52D017;width: 300px;height: 24px;'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</li></span>";     
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a lot of good documentation from Microsoft.

There are a couple good articles here:

[Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

[Client Side Rendering: List Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms)

As well as all the answers to this question:

[Client-Side Rendering/JS Link documentation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/73654/8992)

The first article linked should give you a good overview of the object `RegisterTemplateOverrides()` expects.

The `RenderItemTemplate(ctx)` method may be one of the ones that is exposed/available from the SharePoint rendering system.  A lot of the default stuff is available to use from within your rendering override code, it's just (again) not well documented so you will have to either look through `clienttemplates.debug.js` yourself, of set up a breakpoint and inspect the `ctx` object in a browser.

Here's an answer that lists a lot of the available default rendering methods:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/112940/8992