# Adding an Item where selecting checkboxes populates a textbox field with information

Tags: list, list-view, newform

I have a Sharepoint List with columns "name", "date", "stage", "information".

"stage" is a checkbox column and "information" is a multi-line text box.

Is it possible when a "stage" checkbox is selected while creating new item, form will populate the "information" text box with some default information for the user to see?

If so, how would I implement this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Which SharePoint version?

Comment: Using OOTB functionality it is not possible. To achieve this you need to write custom code and add it in script editor or content editor on new form.

Comment: @Gary Where the information will be stored/ from where you need to get the information?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can attach JSLink to the list-view wepbart with custom code which will handle this functionality. You can see some other examples here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

Comment: I can't seem to find list-view webpart in the create item form. I'm doing this through the website. Is there a tool I should use? I am completely new to SharePoint.

Comment: It is done in other way: you want to develop JSLink which will run on new item creation. Below are the examples how you can accomplish it: 
1. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37203.sharepoint-online-customize-list-view-web-part-using-jslink.aspx
2. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112506/sharepoint-2013-js-link-return-default-field-rendering/112576
3. https://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com/2015/11/use-jslink-to-auto-populate-sharepoint.html

Ask me if you have other questions :)